# Does the limit product rule apply if one limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus

Assume we want to calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) f(x)$.

Moreover, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) = \infty$ and
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = n$ where $n \neq 0$ is some natural number.

Is it possible to conclude:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x).$$

I am kind of insecure since I read on some pages that it is only possible if both limits (i.e. the one of $f$ and $g$) exist. However, on other pages, I read that in the case stated above the claim does hold.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It is true in the sense that if $\lim f(x)g(x)$ does not exist, is infinite, or is indeterminate, then $\lim f(x)\lim g(x)$ will be respectively nonexistent, infinite, or indeterminate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That means it is not possible to conlcude from the right-hand side $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) f(x) $ does not exist?

Comment: @JoshuaWang , sorry I forgot to tag you in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

The expression
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)
$$
makes no sense, as $\infty$ isn't a number and you can't do arithmetic with it.

However, *as a mnemonic device*, saying that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) f(x)$ is of "type $\infty\cdot n$", and therefore diverges to infinity is fine, after you prove that this is indeed always the case for $n\neq0$.

Comment: Well, it makes sense if you think of $\mathbf R\cup \{\infty,-\infty\}$ as a set equipped with partial algebraic operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, I do not really need to prove this. But I would need the implication that from the right hand side $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \infty$ the left hand side $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) f(x) = \infty $ can be concluded. Thus, do you mean with "diverges to infinity is fine" that my previous claim holds?